# How to divide numbers to the power of something by a number to the power of something

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I'm having troubling dividing numbers to the power of something by another number to the power of something... For example,

$$C\,(-4)^n = -2\,C\,(-4)^{n-1} + 8\,C\,(-4)^{n-2} + 3\,(-4)^n$$

I'm dividing both sides by $(-4)^{n-2}$ ...

I understand that $\;8\,C\,(-4)^{n-2} / (-4)^{n-2}\;$ is $\,8\,C\,$ but all other calculations i.e. $\,C\,(-4)^n / (-4)^{n-2}$, $-2\,C\,(-4)^{n-1} / (-4)^{n-2}$ and $3\,(-4)^n / (-4)^{n-2}\;$ I don't know how to do.

Please help!

Comment: No one can understand you the way you write mathematical expressions with plain text,... here's a MathJax tutorial (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hint: replace the divisions by $(-4)^{n-2}$ with multiplications by $(-4)^{2-n}$ and simplify the exponents.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni for 3(-4)^n / (-4)^(n-2) I got 3(-4)^(n-2), however, the answers just say it equals 48... how is this so?

Comment: Well not really (I'll detail my suggestion) : $\;3(-4)^n/(-4)^{n-2}=3(-4)^n(-4)^{2-n}=3(-4)^{n+2-n}=3(-4)^2=48$. Concerning your initial equation multiply by $4^{2-n}$ (which is equivalent to your division) to get : 
\begin{align}
C\,(-4)^{n+2-n} &= -2\,C\,(-4)^{n-1+2-n} + 8\,C\,(-4)^{n-2+2-n} + 3\,(-4)^{n+2-n}\\
C\,(-4)^2 &= -2\,C\,(-4)^1 + 8\,C\,(-4)^0 + 3\,(-4)^2\\
\end{align}
Compute the powers and put the $C$ terms at the left to conclude. Excellent continuation,